# Change variables in bash

Tags: bash

How do I change this var ?

```
max=0;
min=20000000;
cat |while read
do
    read a
    if [[ $a -gt $max ]]
    then
        max=a`
    fi
    `if [[ $a -lt $min ]]
    then
        min=a
    fi
done
echo $max 
echo $min
```

My min and max are still the same, 0 and 2000000. Can anybody help me with this ? I have no idea.

Comment: also `max=a` should be `max=$a`, same with `min=a` should be `min=$a`

Comment: What should be `min` if every values are greater than 20000000 ? I guess that `min` and `max` should be your first value...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered)

Answer (score 46):

The (main) problem with your script is that setting `min` and `max` happens in a subshell, not your main shell. So the changes aren't visible after the pipeline is done.

Another one is that you're calling read twice - this might be intended if you want to skip every other line, but that's a bit unusual.

The last one is that `min=a` sets `min` to `a`, literally. You want to set it to `$a`.

Using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to get rid of the first problem, removing the (possibly) un-necessary second read, and fixing the assignments, your code should look like:

```
max=0
min=20000000
while read a
do
    if [[ $a -gt $max ]]
    then
        max=$a
    fi
    if [[ $a -lt $min ]]
    then
        min=$a
    fi
done < <(cat)    # careful with the syntax
echo $max 
echo $min
```

---

Comment: 4th problem: unmotivated backticks in the middle of the script, not explainable by beginner mistake. :)

Comment: In Bash (and Ksh and Zsh), I recommend this form: `if (( a > max ))`. Also, if `cat` is not a placeholder for something else, then the whole redirection and process substitution can be eliminated since the script will read from `stdin` by default anyway.