# A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered

Tags: bash, while-loop, scope, sh

In the following program, if I set the variable `$foo` to the value 1 inside the first `if` statement, it works in the sense that its value is remembered after the if statement. However, when I set the same variable to the value 2 inside an `if` which is inside a `while` statement, it's forgotten after the `while` loop. It's behaving like I'm using some sort of copy of the variable `$foo` inside the `while` loop and I am modifying only that particular copy. Here's a complete test program:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u 
foo=0
bar="hello"  
if [[ "$bar" == "hello" ]]
then
    foo=1
    echo "Setting \$foo to 1: $foo"
fi

echo "Variable \$foo after if statement: $foo"   
lines="first line\nsecond line\nthird line" 
echo -e $lines | while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" == "second line" ]]
    then
    foo=2
    echo "Variable \$foo updated to $foo inside if inside while loop"
    fi
    echo "Value of \$foo in while loop body: $foo"
done

echo "Variable \$foo after while loop: $foo"

# Output:
# $ ./testbash.sh
# Setting $foo to 1: 1
# Variable $foo after if statement: 1
# Value of $foo in while loop body: 1
# Variable $foo updated to 2 inside if inside while loop
# Value of $foo in while loop body: 2
# Value of $foo in while loop body: 2
# Variable $foo after while loop: 1

# bash --version
# GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
```

Comment: Key reading here: [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: The shellcheck utility catches this (see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2030);  Cut and pasting the above code in  https://shellcheck.net issues this feedback for Line 19:
`SC2030: Modification of foo is local (to subshell caused by pipeline).`

Answer (score 351, accepted):

```
echo -e $lines | while read line 
    ...
done
```

The `while` loop is executed in a subshell. So any changes you do to the variable will not be available once the subshell exits.

Instead you can use a [*here string*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) to re-write the while loop to be in the main shell process; only `echo -e $lines` will run in a subshell:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" == "second line" ]]
    then
        foo=2
        echo "Variable \$foo updated to $foo inside if inside while loop"
    fi
    echo "Value of \$foo in while loop body: $foo"
done <<< "$(echo -e "$lines")"
```

You can get rid of the rather ugly `echo` in the here-string above by expanding the backslash sequences immediately when assigning `lines`. The `$'...'` form of quoting can be used there:

```
lines=$'first line\nsecond line\nthird line'
while read line; do
    ...
done <<< "$lines"
```

Comment: better change `<<< "$(echo -e "$lines")"` to simple `<<< "$lines"`

Comment: what if the source was from `tail -f` instead of fixed text?

Comment: @mteee You can use `while read -r line; do echo "LINE: $line"; done < <(tail -f file)` (obviously the loop won't terminate as it continues to wait for input from `tail`).

Comment: I'm limited to /bin/sh - is there an alternative way that works in the old shell?

Comment: @user9645 You could print from the subshell and get the result. E.g., `myfunc() { echo -e "1\n2\n3\n" | (while read line; do count=\`expr $count + 1\`; done; echo $count;)  }`  then `val=\`myfunc\``.

Comment: This issue is only with `while` loop, `for` loops work perfectly.

Comment: @AvinashYadav The problem isn't really related to `while` loop or `for` loop; rather the use of subshell i.e., in `cmd1 | cmd2`, `cmd2` is in a subshell. So if a `for` loop is executed in a subshell, the unexpected/problematic behaviour will be exhibited.

Comment: emacs "helpfully" decides that once I type "done <<" that it should immediately insert some "EOF" crap

Comment: I am getting this error when using above syntax "Syntax error: redirection unexpected". is any alternative solution ?

Comment: @NavinGelot Are you using bash shell? Do you have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script?

Comment: I'm using this where `$lines` are file-paths with spaces in them. In this case, non of the solutions using `echo` worked. Instead the `done <<< $lines` did the job correctly.

Comment: @P.P Your comment about the root cause helped me solve my problem. Not a while/for issue, but a subshell issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 60):

**UPDATED#2**

Explanation is in Blue Moons's answer.

Alternative solutions:

Eliminate `echo`

```
while read line; do
...
done <<EOT
first line
second line
third line
EOT
```

Add the echo inside the here-is-the-document

```
while read line; do
...
done <<EOT
$(echo -e $lines)
EOT
```

Run `echo` in background:

```
coproc echo -e $lines
while read -u ${COPROC[0]} line; do 
...
done
```

Redirect to a file handle explicitly (Mind the space in `< <`!):

```
exec 3< <(echo -e  $lines)
while read -u 3 line; do
...
done
```

Or just redirect to the `stdin`:

```
while read line; do
...
done < <(echo -e  $lines)
```

And one for `chepner` (eliminating `echo`):

```
arr=("first line" "second line" "third line");
for((i=0;i<${#arr[*]};++i)) { line=${arr[i]}; 
...
}
```

Variable `$lines` can be converted to an array without starting a new sub-shell. The characters `\` and `n` has to be converted to some character (e.g. a real new line character) and use the IFS (Internal Field Separator) variable to split the string into array elements. This can be done like:

```
lines="first line\nsecond line\nthird line"
echo "$lines"
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n' arr=(${lines//\\n/$'\n'}) # Conversion
IFS="$OIFS"
echo "${arr[@]}", Length: ${#arr[*]}
set|grep ^arr
```

Result is

```
first line\nsecond line\nthird line
first line second line third line, Length: 3
arr=([0]="first line" [1]="second line" [2]="third line")
```

Comment: +1 for the here-doc, since the `lines` variable's only purpose seems to be to feed the `while` loop.

Comment: @chepner: Thx! I added another one, dedicated to You!

Comment: There is yet another solution given [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197183/36095): `for line in $(echo -e $lines); do ... done`

Comment: @dma_k Thanks for your comment! This solution would result 6 lines containing a single word. OP's request was different...

Comment: upvoted. running echo in a subshell inside here-is, was one of the few solutions that worked in ash

Comment: Running with `$(echo -e $lines)` (in a subshell), is not necessary if `$lines` is properly formatted. Worked great with just `for line in $lines`. If you, for some reason, trying to  use *Cygwin*, you will find that `done < <(echo -e  $lines)` or `exec 3< <(echo -e  $lines)` does **not** work there, AFAICT.

Answer (score 10):

You are asking this [bash FAQ.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell) The answer also describes the general case of variables set in subshells created by pipes:

> E4) *If I pipe the output of a command into `read variable`, why
> doesn't the output show up in `$variable` when the read command finishes?*
>
> This has to do with the parent-child relationship between Unix
> processes.  It affects all commands run in pipelines, not just
> simple calls to `read`.  For example, piping a command's output
> into a `while` loop that repeatedly calls `read` will result in
> the same behavior.

> Each element of a pipeline, even a builtin or shell function,
> runs in a separate process, a child of the shell running the
> pipeline.  A subprocess cannot affect its parent's environment.
> When the `read` command sets the variable to the input, that
> variable is set only in the subshell, not the parent shell.  When
> the subshell exits, the value of the variable is lost.

> Many pipelines that end with `read variable` can be converted
> into command substitutions, which will capture the output of
> a specified command.  The output can then be assigned to a
> variable:

> ```
> grep ^gnu /usr/lib/news/active | wc -l | read ngroup
> ```

> can be converted into

> ```
> ngroup=$(grep ^gnu /usr/lib/news/active | wc -l)
> ```

> This does not, unfortunately, work to split the text among
> multiple variables, as read does when given multiple variable
> arguments.  If you need to do this, you can either use the
> command substitution above to read the output into a variable
> and chop up the variable using the bash pattern removal
> expansion operators or use some variant of the following
> approach.

> Say /usr/local/bin/ipaddr is the following shell script:

> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> host `hostname` | awk '/address/ {print $NF}'
> ```

> Instead of using

> ```
> /usr/local/bin/ipaddr | read A B C D
> ```

> to break the local machine's IP address into separate octets, use

> ```
> OIFS="$IFS"
> IFS=.
> set -- $(/usr/local/bin/ipaddr)
> IFS="$OIFS"
> A="$1" B="$2" C="$3" D="$4"
> ```

> Beware, however, that this will change the shell's positional
> parameters.  If you need them, you should save them before doing
> this.

> This is the general approach -- in most cases you will not need to
> set $IFS to a different value.

> Some other user-supplied alternatives include:

> ```
> read A B C D << HERE
>     $(IFS=.; echo $(/usr/local/bin/ipaddr))
> HERE
> ```

> and, where process substitution is available,

> ```
> read A B C D < <(IFS=.; echo $(/usr/local/bin/ipaddr))
> ```

Comment: You forgot the *Family Feud* problem. Sometimes it’s very hard to find the same combination of words as whoever wrote the answer, so that you’re neither flooded in wrong results, nor filter out said answer.

Comment: Link is marked "This document is no longer maintained".

Comment: @GrahamLeggett Link replaced.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm... I would almost swear that this worked for the original Bourne shell, but don't have access to a running copy just now to check.

There is, however, a very trivial workaround to the problem.

Change the first line of the script from:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

Et voila! A read at the end of a pipeline works just fine, assuming you have the Korn shell installed.

Comment: zsh works as well.

Answer (score 2):

I use stderr to store within a loop, and read from it outside.
Here var i is initially set and read inside the loop as 1.

```
# reading lines of content from 2 files concatenated
# inside loop: write value of var i to stderr (before iteration)
# outside: read var i from stderr, has last iterative value

f=/tmp/file1
g=/tmp/file2
i=1
cat $f $g | \
while read -r s;
do
  echo $s > /dev/null;  # some work
  echo $i > 2
  let i++
done;
read -r i < 2
echo $i
```

Or use the heredoc method to reduce the amount of code in a subshell.
Note the iterative i value can be read outside the while loop.

```
i=1
while read -r s;
do
  echo $s > /dev/null
  let i++
done <<EOT
$(cat $f $g)
EOT
let i--
echo $i
```

Comment: Very useful.  You can have multiple variables in the while loop, and echo each of them out to a different number `echo $i > 2; echo $j > 3`.  Then you can redirect each of them back to the global variables after the while loop `read -r i < 2; read -r j < 3`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and touches on a very basic concept in Bourne shell and subshell.  Here I provide a solution that is different from the previous solutions by doing some kind of filtering. I will give an example that may be useful in real life. This is a fragment for checking that downloaded files conform to a known checksum. The checksum file look like the following (Showing just 3 lines):

```
49174 36326 dna_align_feature.txt.gz
54757     1 dna.txt.gz
55409  9971 exon_transcript.txt.gz
```

The shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

.....

failcnt=0 # this variable is only valid in the parent shell
#variable xx captures all the outputs from the while loop
xx=$(cat ${checkfile} | while read -r line; do
    num1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
    num2=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
    fname=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
    if [ -f "$fname" ]; then
        res=$(sum $fname)
        filegood=$(sum $fname | awk -v na=$num1 -v nb=$num2 -v fn=$fname '{ if (na == $1 && nb == $2) { print "TRUE"; } else { print "FALSE"; }}')
        if [ "$filegood" = "FALSE" ]; then
            failcnt=$(expr $failcnt + 1) # only in subshell
            echo "$fname BAD $failcnt"
        fi
    fi
done | tail -1) # I am only interested in the final result
# you can capture a whole bunch of texts and do further filtering
failcnt=${xx#* BAD } # I am only interested in the number
# this variable is in the parent shell
echo failcnt $failcnt
if [ $failcnt -gt 0 ]; then
    echo $failcnt files failed
else
    echo download successful
fi
```

The parent and subshell communicate through the echo command.  You can pick some easy to parse text for the parent shell.  This method does not break your normal way of thinking, just that you have to do some post processing. You can use grep, sed, awk, and more for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

How about a very simple method

```
    +call your while loop in a function 
     - set your value inside (nonsense, but shows the example)
     - return your value inside 
    +capture your value outside
    +set outside
    +display outside


    #!/bin/bash
    # set -e
    # set -u
    # No idea why you need this, not using here

    foo=0
    bar="hello"

    if [[ "$bar" == "hello" ]]
    then
        foo=1
        echo "Setting  \$foo to $foo"
    fi

    echo "Variable \$foo after if statement: $foo"

    lines="first line\nsecond line\nthird line"

    function my_while_loop
    {

    echo -e $lines | while read line
    do
        if [[ "$line" == "second line" ]]
        then
        foo=2; return 2;
        echo "Variable \$foo updated to $foo inside if inside while loop"
        fi

        echo -e $lines | while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" == "second line" ]]
    then
    foo=2;          
    echo "Variable \$foo updated to $foo inside if inside while loop"
    return 2;
    fi

    # Code below won't be executed since we returned from function in 'if' statement
    # We aready reported the $foo var beint set to 2 anyway
    echo "Value of \$foo in while loop body: $foo"

done
}

    my_while_loop; foo="$?"

    echo "Variable \$foo after while loop: $foo"


    Output:
    Setting  $foo 1
    Variable $foo after if statement: 1
    Value of $foo in while loop body: 1
    Variable $foo after while loop: 2

    bash --version

    GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
    Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Maybe there's a decent answer under the surface here, but you've butchered the formatting to the point that it's unpleasant to try and read.

Comment: You mean the original code is pleasant to read? (I've just followed :p)

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question and asked several times, here's what I'm doing after hours fidgeting with `here` strings, and the only option that worked for me is to store the value in a file during while loop sub-shells and then retrieve it. Simple.

Use `echo` statement to store and `cat` statement to retrieve. And the bash user must `chown` the directory or have read-write `chmod` access.

```
#write to file
echo "1" > foo.txt

while condition; do 
    if (condition); then
        #write again to file
        echo "2" > foo.txt      
    fi
done

#read from file
echo "Value of \$foo in while loop body: $(cat foo.txt)"
```

Comment: Did you try this?
`xxx=0; while true; do if true; then  xxx=100 ; fi; break; done; echo $xxx `