# Incrementing a variable inside a Bash loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I'm trying to write a small script that will count entries in a log file, and I'm incrementing  a variable (`USCOUNTER`) which I'm trying to use after the loop is done.

But at that moment `USCOUNTER` looks to be 0 instead of the actual value. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
FILE=$1

tail -n10 mylog > $FILE

USCOUNTER=0

cat $FILE | while read line; do
  country=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1)
  if [ "US" = "$country" ]; then
        USCOUNTER=`expr $USCOUNTER + 1`
        echo "US counter $USCOUNTER"
  fi
done
echo "final $USCOUNTER"
```

It outputs:

```
US counter 1
US counter 2
US counter 3
..
final 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You are using `USCOUNTER` in a subshell, that's why the variable is not showing in the main shell.

Instead of `cat FILE | while ...`, do just a `while ... done < $FILE`. This way, you avoid the common problem of [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024):

```
while read country _; do
  if [ "US" = "$country" ]; then
        USCOUNTER=$(expr $USCOUNTER + 1)
        echo "US counter $USCOUNTER"
  fi
done < "$FILE"
```

Note I also replaced the `` expression with a $().

I also replaced `while read line; do country=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1)` with `while read country _`. This allows you to say `while read var1 var2 ... varN` where `var1` contains the first word in the line, `$var2` and so on, until `$varN` containing the remaining content.

Comment: Note you can use $(($USCOUNTER+1)) to evaluate the expression

Comment: Thanks @geert3, good one. Also `((USCOUNTER++))` as anubhava's solution is using. I am not adding it to my answer in case it is incompatible with OPs shell.

Answer (score 30):

minimalist

```
counter=0
((counter++))
echo $counter
```

Comment: Some explanations would be appreciated

Comment: Where is the wanted while loop in your example ?

Comment: echo $((++counter))

Answer (score 29):

- [Always use `-r` with read](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#read_without_-r).
- There is no need to use `cut`, you can stick with pure bash solutions.

  - In this case passing `read` a 2nd var (`_`) to catch the additional "fields"
- [Prefer `[[ ]]` over `[ ]`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).
- Use [arithmetic expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr).
- Do not forget to [quote variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)! Link includes other pitfalls as well

```
while read -r country _; do
  if [[ $country = 'US' ]]; then
    ((USCOUNTER++))
    echo "US counter $USCOUNTER"
  fi
done < "$FILE"
```

Comment: Why not `echo "US counter $((USCOUNTER++))"` within the if?

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński if you want it to be equivalent to the code above, then you should use ``"US counter $((++USCOUNTER))"``. That's a very good point, you are right!

Answer (score 16):

You're getting `final 0` because your `while loop` is being executed in a sub (shell) process and any changes made there are not reflected in the current (parent) shell.

**Correct script:**

```
while read -r country _; do
  if [ "US" = "$country" ]; then
        ((USCOUNTER++))
        echo "US counter $USCOUNTER"
  fi
done < "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same $count variable in a while loop getting lost issue.

[@fedorqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20681248/474411) (and a few others) are accurate answers to the actual question: the sub-shell is indeed the problem.

But it lead me to another issue: I wasn't piping a file content... but the output of a series of pipes & greps...

my erroring sample code:

```
count=0
cat /etc/hosts | head | while read line; do
  ((count++))
  echo $count $line
done
echo $count
```

and my fix thanks to the help of this thread and the [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst#avoiding_subshells):

```
count=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  ((count++))
  echo "$count $line"
done < <(cat /etc/hosts | head)
echo "$count"
```

Comment: Nice to see my answer was helpful :) Note also that `cat file | head` can be simplified to `head file`.

Answer (score 1):

```
USCOUNTER=$(grep -c "^US " "$FILE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing a variable can be done like that:

```
  _my_counter=$[$_my_counter + 1]
```

Counting the number of occurrence of a pattern in a column can be done with grep

```
 grep -cE "^([^ ]* ){2}US"
```

`-c` count

`([^ ]* )` To detect a colonne

`{2}` the colonne number

`US` your pattern

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: The title is: "Bash incrementing variable in loop"
My line does: "incrementing a variable in bash" 
So I think it does answer a part of the question (at least as much as the example from geekzspot)

Comment: The `$[ ... ]` syntax for arithmetic expansion is [deprecated](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith). Please use `$(( ... ))` instead. Both your answer and geekzspot's address an _incidental_ aspect of the OP's question that doesn't solve the problem (the variable-incrementing part of the OP's code was working (however inefficiently)). If you want to suggest an _incidental_ improvement without answering the question, please clearly state so.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following 1 line command for changing many files name in linux using phrase specificity:

```
find -type f -name '*.jpg' | rename 's/holiday/honeymoon/'
```

For all files with the extension ".jpg", if they contain the string "holiday", replace it with "honeymoon". For instance, this command would rename the file "ourholiday001.jpg" to "ourhoneymoon001.jpg".

This example also illustrates how to use the find command to send a list of files (-type f) with the extension .jpg (-name '*.jpg') to rename via a pipe (|). rename then reads its file list from standard input.