# Bash increment length of string

Tags: bash, shell, string-length

I just want to echo an incremented string length. For example:

```
STR="test"
echo ${#STR}
```

It prints 4, but I want to print 5.

Comment: Yes I tried ${#STR+1} and ${#STR}+1

Comment: echo $(( ${#STR} + 1 ))?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incrementing a variable inside a Bash loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681210/incrementing-a-variable-inside-a-bash-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
STR="test"
count=${#STR}
((count++))
echo $count
```

[`((count++))`: How to increment a variable in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

The length of the string cannot be changed without modifying the string. If you want to add another character at the beginning, try

```sh
STR="a$STR"
```

Now `${#STR}` is 5, because `STR` is `atest` (five characters).

If you want to perform arithmetic in the shell, use an [arithmetic expression](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression):

```sh
echo "$((1+${#STR}))"
```