# Matching the string in a File using IF

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying a find a strings of a file matching with another file and collecting them into an array. As a first step, I tried to find a string matching of two files. I used below code, but strangely I am getting this message `grep: 3: No such file or directory`,`grep: 5: No such file or directory`. I could not figure out the rootcause for this. Can some one help me finding the rootcause? Shell script used:

```
#!/bin/bash
while
read LINE
do
if grep -q $LINE /tmp/UA_Automation/glhard; then
echo "$LINE"
echo "matched"
else
echo "$LINE"
echo "not_matching"
fi
done < /tmp/UA_Automation/UA_daily_listings_unique_count.csv|awk '{ print $1 }'
```

glhard & UA_daily_listings_unique_count.csv are name of the file. Contents of these two files respectively are:

```
glauto
gltyre
gldisc
glclothes
```

```
glwheel 2
glgun 3
glauto 4
gldisc 4
glpants 6
```

Can someone help me figure out this?

Comment: for condition checking purpose. Is this wrong? sorry i don't know bash well.

Comment: It looks like you will be able to do what you want within a single awk one-liner. If you explain what it is you're trying to do in the long-run we will be able to help you more.

Comment: @TomFenech: Any idea what is the rootcause?

Comment: The file with all the patterns has numbers on each line, but the file you're searching doesn't have these numbers. So nothing will match them. Do you want to ignore the numbers?

Comment: @Avinash `if` checks the return code of the following expression. The return code of `grep -q` will indicate whether there was a match or not. `[[` should not be used in this case.

Comment: @Tom: I want to collect contents of file:UA_daily* which are matching with contents of file:glhard. Contents of both files are different, but may contain common strings. When the contents are matching, as a next step, I would be storing them like `{c[$1]++} END` as there may be number of matches.

Comment: @Barmar: I used `awk '{ print $1 }'` just to ignore the numbers when it goes into `while` loop

Comment: `awk` is getting the output of the while loop, it's not being used for the input.

Comment: @user3624000 You should edit your question to include these details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're piping the *output* of the loop to `awk`. You want to go the other way:

```
awk '{print $1}' /tmp/UA_Automation/UA_daily_listings_unique_count.csv | while read LINE
do
    if grep -q $LINE /tmp/UA_Automation/glhard; then
        echo "$LINE"
        echo "matched"
    else
        echo "$LINE"
        echo "not_matching"
    fi
done
```

Although you could also make use of `read` splitting the line:

```
while read LINE NUMBER
do 
    ...
done < /tmp/UA_Automation/UA_daily_listings_unique_count.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. As a next step, I have collected matching strings into an array. I declared global array(outside of while loop) so that I can use them wherever I want globally. But outside of while loop, its not giving the contents I expected. I used like this `array=()
awk '{ print $1}' /tmp/UA_Automation/UA_daily_crawled_listings_unique_withglinfo_count.csv|while read LINE
do
if grep -q $LINE /tmp/UA_Automation/glhardlines; then
echo "$LINE matching"
array+=("$LINE")
else
echo "$LINE not_matching"
fi
done
echo ${#array[@]}`

Comment: Any corrections you would like to suggest me? The statement `echo ${#array[@]}` gives 0 as output.

Comment: I can't read that easily, there's no formatting in comments. You should append it to the question if you're still having trouble.

Comment: `+=` doesn't add an element to an array in `bash`, so I don't know what you expect `array+=("$LINE")` to do. You need to increment a variable `$i` and use `array[$i]=$LINE`

Comment: Declaring array globally doesn't work? Statement `echo ${#array[@]}` gives me 0 as output. I was expecting output to be "2". Any ideas??

Comment: Commands in a pipeline are run in a subshell, so any variable assignments they make are not visible after the `while` loop ends.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/modifying-variable-inside-while-loop-is-not-remembered

Answer (score 1):

The value of `LINE` contains whitespace; you need to quote it so that the entire value is used as the pattern, not just the first word after word-splitting.

```
if grep -q "$LINE" /tmp/UA_Automation/glhard; then
```

That said, I'd recommend looking at `diff` or `comm` for such line-by-line comparisons of files, rather than running `grep` for each line.

Comment: Probably? He showed the contents of the file, it's the ones with the numbers at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Fixed.

Comment: This still won't work. He probably just wants to search for the first word, not the whole line.

Comment: It solves the problem presented in the question. If the resulting working code has a semantic error, that's another issue.