# *export* all variables from key=value file to shell

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, export

If I want to inherit environment variables to child processes, i do something like:

```
export MYVAR=tork
```

Assume I have a a file `site.conf` containing assignments of values (that can contain spaces) to variables:

```
EMAIL="dev@example.com"
FULLNAME="Master Yedi"
FOO=bar
```

Now I would like to process this file whenever I open a new shell (e.g. with some code in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`), so that any processes started from within that newly opened shell will inherit the assignments via environmental variables.

The obvious solution would be to prefix each line in `site.conf` with an `export` and just source the file. However I cannot do this since the file is also read (directly) by some other applications, so the format is fixed.

I tried something like

```
cat site.conf | while read assignment
do
  export "${assignment}"
done
```

But this doesn't work, for various reasons (the most important being that `export` is executed in a subshell, so the variable will never be exported to the children of the calling shell).

Is there a way to programmatically `export` unknown variables in bash?

Comment: Related: [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16854280/6862601).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Run `set -a` before sourcing the file. This marks all new and modified variables that follow for export automatically.

```
set -a
source site.conf
set +a  # Require export again, if desired.
```

---

The problem you observed is that the pipe executes the `export` in a subshell. You can avoid that simply by using input redirection instead of a pipe.

```
while read assignment; do
  export "$assignment"
done < site.conf
```

This won't work, however, if (unlikely though it is) you have multiple assignments on one line, such as

```
EMAIL="dev@example.com" FULLNAME="Master Yedi"
```

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect, `export` will still work with multiple affectations in a single line.

Comment: `export` does, but the need to quote `$assignment` breaks it. A line like `foo=1 bar=2` results in `export "foo=1 bar=2"`, which sets `foo` to `1 bar =2`. Writing `export $assignment` wouldn't work if any of the values were quoted: `assignment='foo="hello world"'` results in an attempt to define an environment variable named `world"`, and `assignment='foo="hello"'` results in the value of `foo` being `"hello"`, not `hello`.

Comment: Using an array and `export "${assignment[@]}"` would work, assuming you could parse a series of assignments into an array; that is beyond `read`'s capabilities in general.

Comment: Indeed, I missed the space issue. Leaving the variable unquoted and using `eval` would be simpler and allow the multiple assignments case.

Comment: `eval` introduces even worse issues.

Comment: Just curious is there any functional difference between `export $(xargs <site.conf)` and `set -a; source site.conf; set +a`? Any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: The second is preferable by far; the first assumes that word-splitting and pathname expansion won't make any changes to the output of `xargs` before `export` sees them.