# Bash array declaration and appendation

Tags: arrays, bash, append, declare

I'm trying to declare and append to an array in a bash script, after searching i resulted in this code.

```
list=()
list+="string"
```

But when i echo this out it results in nothing.
I have also tried appending to the array like this

```
list[$[${#list[@]}+1]]="string"
```

I don't understand why this is not working, anyone have any suggestions?

---

**EDIT:**
The problem is list is appended to inside a while loop.

```
list=()

git ls-remote origin 'refs/heads/*' | while read sha ref; do
    list[${#list[@]}+1]="$ref"
done

declare -p list
```

see stackoverflow.com/q/16854280/1126841

Comment: How are you echo-ing it out?

Comment: I have tried ' echo "${list}" ', ' echo "$list" ' and ' echo $list '

Comment: Can you try `echo "${list[0]}"`

Comment: Still returns nothing

Comment: try list+=('foo')

Comment: The list is still empty after list+=('foo')

Comment: @A.Jac Cannot reproduce your first error; `$list` and `${list[0]}` are effectively equivalent. `list+="string"` won't add `string` to the array, but it will append `string` to the end of the first element of the array (creating said element if necessary).

Comment: `$[...]` is obsolete (use `$((...))` instead) and unnecessary; the index of a regular array is automatically evaluated in an arithmetic context, so `list[${#list[@]}+1]="string"` would be sufficient.

Comment: By the way, you can see what bash thinks about that variable by running `declare -p list`. If it is an array will be printed like `declare -a list=<values>.`

Comment: ok, so i tried `list[${#list[@]}+1]="string"` and `declare -p list` it results in `declare -a list='()'`

Comment: Not sure what is going on: I get `declare -a list='([1]="string")'`.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is incompatibility between bash and zsh (which im using). But shouldn't be an issue since i have shebang added

Comment: The problem seems to be my lack of shell knowledge, since the appending is happening inside a while loop it is not remembered after loop is done, need to find a workaround for it.

Comment: The loop wouldn't happen to be in a pipeline, would it? This is a *completely* different problem, and this is why your question needs to provide an example that actually reproduces your problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16854280/1126841.

Answer (score 8):

You can append new string to your array like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mylist=("number one")

#append "number two" to array    
mylist=("${mylist[@]}" "number two")

# print each string in a loop
for mystr in "${mylist[@]}"; do echo "$mystr"; done
```

For more information you can check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays

Comment: The OP is already using the correct operator to append to an array; this won't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ali Okan Yüksel has written down an answer for the first method you mentioned about adding items in an array.

```
list+=( newitem  another_new_item ··· )
```

The right way of the second method you mentioned is:

```
list[${#list[@]}]="string"
```

Assuming that a **non-sparse** array has `N` items and because bash array indexes starts from `0`, the last item in the array is `N-1`th. Therefore the next item must be added in the `N` position (`${#list[@]}`); not necessarily in `N+1` as you wrote.

Instead, if a **sparse** array is used, it is very useful the [bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) which provides the indexes of the array:

```
${!list[@]}
```

For instance,

```
$ list[0]=3
$ list[12]=32
$ echo ${#list[@]}
2
$ echo ${!list[@]}
0 12
```