# Which is the best way to write a loop that reads from a file?

Tags: bash, loops

I'm learning bash and trying to understand the difference between these two methods of reading lines from a file.

1.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo $line
done < "$file"
```

2.

```
cat $file |
while read data
do
   echo $i
done
```

So basically what I'm wondering is:
Is either of them more common practice than the other? Are there performance differences? etc.

Also, are there other ways of reading from a file that are even better, especially when it comes to reading from large files?

Comment: See [BashFAQ/001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is a Useless Use of Cat: http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

I use the `done < "$file"` form.

No, there is not a better way in Bash.  But eliminating one process (`cat`) is nice.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few advantages in the first method:

- it's more straightforward
- it doesn't use an extra `cat` and pipe
- the loop runs in the current shell whereas the second method uses a subshell; variables set or modified inside the loop are *visible* outside

Even if the while loop were to consume the output of another command (through process substitution as shown below), the first method is better as it eliminates the subshell:

```
while read -r line; do
  # loop steps
done < <(_command_)
```

---

See also:

- [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered)
- [BashFAQ/001 - How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- [BashFAQ/024 - I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)
- [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601)