# Adding variable into BASH array

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm having trouble getting the value of a variable into an array in Bash (I'm using bash v3.2.25).

I have some output from a command, piped into:

```
while read domain; do domains=("${domains[@]}" "domain"); done
```

But then `echo ${#domains[@]}` returns 0.

I've also tried various forms of:

```
while read domain; do domains+=($domain); done
```

with all sorts of attempts at quoting and double quoting, but no matter what, the domains array stays empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't have the second `domain` in quotes, should you?

Comment: Specifically, either `domains=("${domains[@]}" "$domain")` (with `$`) or `domains+=("$domain")` should work, but the changes get lost when your `while` loop ends.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered) talks about getting around that problem.

Comment: In what context is this code called? Almost certainly it's in a pipeline -- you need to **show** us that pipeline. See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, it was in a pipeline. I didn't find the answers when searching because I didn't realise the while loop was the problem - I was looking for array help.

The question that this has been linked to has given me the answers I needed :)