# How to access variable value, defined in braces outside braces?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I have working `shell` (not `bash`) code, that splits string to varialbes:

```
sh """
version='1.2.3.4'

echo \$version | { IFS=. read a b c d; echo \$a; }

echo \"a\" \$a
"""
```

Here is output:

```
+ version=1.2.3.4
+ IFS=. read a b c d
+ echo 1.2.3.4
+ echo 1
1
+ echo a
a
```

**Problem:**

I can't access values of `a,b,c,d` outside braces

**Question:**

How can I access these variables?

---

**UPD:**

I run this code via `jenkins` `pipeline`, which let me use such approach. If I try to use another one, it just ignores attempt to parse string:

```
stage('test') {
    steps {
        sh """
        version='1.2.3.4'

        IFS=. read a b c d <<EOF
        \$version
        EOF

        echo \"a\" \$a
        """
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] sh
[ScpPipeline] Running shell script
+ version=1.2.3.4
+ IFS=. read a b c d
[Pipeline] }
```

---

**UPD_1:**

Problem was in spaces and tabs... 0_o So this is working variant (but ugly):

```
stage('test') {
    steps {
sh """
version='1.2.3.4'

IFS=. read a b c d <<EOF
\$version
EOF

echo \"a\" \$a \"b\" \$b \"c\" \$c \"d\" \$d
"""
    }
}
```

Comment: It is because it is defined in a sub-shell, everything after `|` is run is child shell and especially the variable assignments are lost

Comment: [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024): "I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"

Comment: Thanks, but using `{}` is the only way for me to split string... I tryed different ways, but nothing work if I insert `shell` code as part of `jenkins` `pipeline`(

Comment: No; using `{}` is not the only way to split the string.  There are many other ways to do it, some built-in to Bash, others invoking external programs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I found the main problem - there were spaces and tabs in my code. They broke everething) Now it works, but code looks bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a here document instead of a pipe.

```
sh """
version='1.2.3.4'

IFS=. read a b c d <<EOF
\$version
EOF

echo \"a\" \$a
"""
```

Comment: Do you think I should dupe this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered? I don't see why not. I thought since you've answered it, may be you had a good reason not to

Comment: Sure; most of the time, I'm just too lazy to look for a dupe when it would be faster to just write an answer. In this case, I was thinking there might be something specific to the Jenkins context, but there really isn't.

Comment: Please, see updated answer. I try to run your code, but it's ignored. I run it as step of `jenkins` `pipline` and there are a lot of limitations(

Comment: You can't indent the here-document, at least not with arbitrary whitespace.

Comment: @chepner, omg! Your code work correct, if I remove all tabs and spaces in script! Thank you! Do you have any idea how to avoid removing all spaces and tabs?

Comment: Actually, you can indent the *contents* here, since `read` will strip any leading whitespace. If you switch from `<<` to `<<-`, you can indent the delimiter with *tabs only* and it will work.