# Modifying a global variable inside a sub shell in bash

Tags: bash

I know this question has been asked a lot of time, but trust me i have tried many suggestions. What i am trying to do is
continiously monitor the logfile of a tomcat server to detect its startup. Its based on this [stack post](https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found)

I have modified it a little bit to add a timeout so that it won't wait for ever if the string is not present at all in the file.
The code looks like below.

```
echo 0 > flag
timeout  $DEPLOY_WAIT tail -n0 -F $TOMCAT_LOG | while read LOGLINE
do
  [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"INFO: Server startup in"* ]]  && echo 1 > flag && pkill -P $$ timeout
done
x=$(cat flag)
if [ $x -ne 0 ];then
```

Here you can see i am writing to a flag file to detect whether the tail timed out out or if it found a matching string in the file.
If i change it to a variable like

```
flag=0
timeout  $DEPLOY_WAIT tail -n0 -F $TOMCAT_LOG | while read LOGLINE
do
  [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"INFO: Server startup in"* ]]  && flag=1 && pkill -P $$ timeout
done
if [ $flag -ne 0];then
```

then the variable flag always have the value 0. The update done in the while loop is lost. I did some research and found out that this is because the pipe is causing bash to spawn a new sub shell and parameter are passed from parent to child and not vice versa. A solution suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered) 
was to rewrite the thing without using pipes like

```
flag=0
while read LOGLINE;
do
  [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"INFO: Server startup in"* ]]  && flag=1 && pkill -P $$ timeout
done <<< $(timeout  $DEPLOY_WAIT tail -n0 -F $TOMCAT_LOG)
if [ $flag -ne 0];then
```

The problem with this solution is that the data is give to the while loop only after the command timeout completes[and the code to detect the timeout process and kill it also changes. But doesn't matter, so not included] and i am not able to detect the string as soon as it arrives in the file. The script waits for the period of the timeout, no matter what. I am looking for way to combine the two into a single elegant solution not using files as flag.

Comment: You are making things hard on yourself. Search for `inotifywait` on StackOverflow. You can use it to monitor your log for changes and do whatever you need when your log changes. (pay attention to the `-m` and `-e` options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the solution you tried:

```
done <<< $(timeout  $DEPLOY_WAIT tail -n0 -F $TOMCAT_LOG)
```

is that you're capturing the entire output of the `timeout ...` command with `$( )` as a string (which means that it *must* wait until the process exits), and then passing that to the loop as a here-string (with `<<<`). In order for the loop to process output as it's produced, you need to mimic a pipe, like this:

```
done < <(timeout  $DEPLOY_WAIT tail -n0 -F $TOMCAT_LOG)
```

This looks similar, but it's quite different in the details. The `<( )` part is called process substitution -- it runs the `timeout ...` command as a subprocess, and effectively inserts a the filename of a named pipe connected to that process's stdout. Then the resulting `< pipename` part makes the loop read from that named pipe. The effect is pretty much the same as a regular pipe (as in your first attempt), except that the loop isn't forced into a subshell.

Comment: this worked for me but had t modify the script a little bit to find and kill the timeout process. Earlier the timeout process had the shell script process  itself has its parent. After this change a new process is created similar to the original shell scirpt and the timeout is running as a child of this process. so had to use the below comamnd to detect it. depoy.sh is the script name. pkill -P \`pgrep -P $$ deploy\` timeout

Answer (score 1):

Use [PIPESTATUS](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars#pipestatus) to check, if the timeout has been reached. In case of an timeout, the return value is 124.

```
$ timeout 1 sleep 2 | read
Terminated
$ echo $PIPESTATUS 
124
$ timeout 2 sleep 1 | read
$ echo $PIPESTATUS 
0
```

And do not kill `timeout`. It terminates itself, if the child dies.