# Grep command returns nothing in shell script

Tags: bash, unix, grep

When I try to extract rows that are matched string which are in another file.But the grep command returns nothing.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="export.txt"
file="filename.csv"
val=`head -n 1 $file`
echo $val>export.csv
cat export.txt | while read line 
do
   val=`echo $line | tr -d '\n'`
echo $val
valu=`grep $val $file`
 echo $valu
done
```

Comment: Please don't use backticks \`, they are discouraged. Use `$(...)` instead. [Obsolete and deprecated syntax in bash](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). So just do `grep -f export.txt filename.csv`?

Comment: I used $(...).But this also not helped me

Comment: There are many issues with the current approach. Too many to list here, as @KamilCuk says, use `grep -f export.txt filename.csv`

Comment: @FredrikPihl.I used that command also that also not helped

Comment: Then show us the content of your files and the expected output. Just a few lines are enough. Update your question with this information and we'll take look. e.g. see [this](https://pastebin.com/VaTkDwgX)

Comment: I added a duplicate, but I removed it again. Two things that are going to bite you for sure: you're modifying variables in a while loop (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered)), and all the unquoted expansions like `grep $val $file` will bite you when `$val` contains blanks.

Comment: your data may need cleaning up. try `dos2unix $file ; dos2unix export.txt` and see if that helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this :

```
grep -f list.txt input.txt
```

Which will extract all the lines from input which match any word from list.txt.

If for some reason you want to save each match, you can do it in a Bash array as :

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a values <<< "$( grep -f list.txt input.txt )"
```

And then you can print a certain match as :

```
echo "${values[1]}"
```

Regards!

Comment: OP stated in comments that this approach didn't work. Waiting for some example data...