# If condition is not working in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, performance-testing

I am monitoring CPU usage and based on that I want to display message. I have written following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset -F limit1=1.0  # Declare variables as floats.
typeset -F limit2=2.0
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo "Server_Name   CPU(%)"
echo "-------------------------------------------"
for server in `more /opt/scripts/server-list1.txt`
do
    scpu1=$( ssh $server cat /proc/stat | awk '/cpu/{printf("%.1f\n"),
    ($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)}' |  awk  '{print $0}' | head -1)
    echo "$server   $scpu1"
done | column -t
echo "-------------------------------------------"
for server in `more /opt/scripts/server-list2.txt`
do
    scpu2=$( ssh $server cat /proc/stat | awk '/cpu/{printf("%.2f\n"),
    ($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)}' |  awk '{print $0}' | head -1)
    echo "$server   $scpu2"
done | column -t
echo "-------------------------------------------"
if [[ $scpu1 -ge $limit2 && $scpu2 -le $limit1 ]] ; then
    echo " CPU utilization of node1 is above 2% and node2 is below 1%"
elif [[ $scpu1 -le $limit1  &&  $scpu2 -ge $limit2 ]] ; then
    echo " CPU utilization of node2 is above 2% and node1 is below 1%"
elif [[ $scpu1 -ge $limit2  &&  $scpu2 -ge $limit2 ]] ; then
    echo "CPU utilization of node1 and node2 is above 2% "
else
    echo " Nothing to do"
fi
```

Though my node1 CPU is less than 2% and node2 CPU is greater than 1% it is giving output as: CPU utilization of node1 is above 2% and node2 is below 1%. Irrespective of condition it is giving the same output as above.

Comment: Not clear, could you please use CODE TAGS properly. Then could you please explain your problem in a concise manner so that we could understand it better, kindly do let us know once you edit your post.

Comment: Till CPU monitoring part script is working fine. But if condition is not working, in the sense in the above script i have 4 conditions, i know 2nd condition is true but  it is giving the first condition output. Irrespective of the condition in if, it is giving the same output as: CPU utilization of node1 is above 2% and node2 is below 1%

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) correctly identifies this problem as a variation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered . Your variables assignments are forgotten because they happen in subshells.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is a bash builtin.

However, `[` is also a shell builtin that redirects to the `test` command.

If you look in the manual of test (`man test`), you can see the following:

```
EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2
    both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true
```

This means, that you should use `-a` should be used instead of `&&` inside of `[ condition ]`.

However, as the manual states later:

```
NOTE: Binary -a and -o are inherently ambiguous.  Use 'test EXPR1  &&  test  EXPR2'  or  'test
EXPR1 || test EXPR2' instead.
```

This means, the best way of doing this is:

```
[[ $scpu1 -ge $limit2 ]] && [[ $scpu2 -le $limit1 ]]
```

As @[that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) points out in the comments of the question:

> [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) correctly identifies this problem as a variation of [stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered) . Your variables assignments are forgotten because they happen in subshells.

You assign variables inside `for` loops, which is ok but the output of the loop is piped to `column -t`. This pipe creates 2 subshells (for the command before and after the pipe) and the variables of subshells is discarded after the subshell ends.

For example, this happens to `scpu1` here:

```
for server in `more /opt/scripts/server-list1.txt`
do
    scpu1=$( ssh $server cat /proc/stat | awk '/cpu/{printf("%.1f\n"),
    ($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)}' |  awk  '{print $0}' | head -1)
    echo "$server   $scpu1"
done | column -t
```

As the answer of the linked post of @[that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) suggests, you can use output redirection(which does not create subshells) for this:

```
for server in `more /opt/scripts/server-list1.txt`
do
    scpu1=$( ssh $server cat /proc/stat | awk '/cpu/{printf("%.1f\n"),
    ($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)}' |  awk  '{print $0}' | head -1)
    echo "$server   $scpu1"
done <<< "$(column -t)"
```

Note that `$()` is a newer version of ``` `` ```

Comment: I have tried this " [[ $scpu1 -ge $limit2 ]] && [[ $scpu2 -le $limit1 ]]  " also, still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: Finishes the script if you add `set -e` at the beginning? This makes the script quit if any errors(return codes that do not equal `0`) occur.

Comment: Also, I've added a reference to the comment of @[that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) explaining another problem with your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will check for that.

Comment: I have removed the for loop and cpu usage is assigning to one variable. It giving output as:
 -------------------------------------------
 Server_Name  CPU(%)
 ------------------------------------------- 
CPU Usage of server1: 1.6 CPU Usage of server2: 3.21 script.sh: line 14: [[: 1.6: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".6") script.sh: line 18: [[: 1.6: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".6") script.sh: line 22: [[: 1.6: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".6") Nothing to do

Comment: you might need to quote the variables with `"`.

Comment: but there may be problems with the floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer highlight additional problems on top of the issues raised by @dan1st answer, in particular, the usage of `| columns`

From the comment on `typeset -F limit1=1.0  # Declare variables as floats.`, it implies that the script is expecting floating point math (comparison, etc). `bash` (like most other `sh` varients) does NOT support arithmetic or comparison on floating point, only integers.

Consider one of two options: performing all math in integers including the load calculation and the limit1/limit2 values). Alternatively, if it's critical to have more precision (fractions of percent), consider scaling all numbers by a factor of 10 (or 100, if that level of precision is needed).

The '-F' of typeset prevent the display of the function body. It is only useful if the function is printed with `typedef -p ...`, otherwise it is ignored.

```
#!/bin/bash


   ### No -F 
typeset limit1=1
typeset limit2=2
   ###
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo "Server_Name   CPU(%)"
echo "-------------------------------------------"
for server in `more /opt/scripts/server-list1.txt`
do
    scpu1=$( ssh $server cat /proc/stat | awk '/cpu/{printf("%.1f\n"),
    ($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)}' |  awk  '{print $0}' | head -1)
    echo "$server   $scpu1"
done | column -t
echo "-------------------------------------------"
for server in `more /opt/scripts/server-list2.txt`
do
    scpu2=$( ssh $server cat /proc/stat | awk '/cpu/{printf("%.2f\n"),
    ($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)}' |  awk '{print $0}' | head -1)
    echo "$server   $scpu2"
done | column -t
echo "-------------------------------------------"

   ### Calculate load (as integer), and compare
load1=$(printf '%.0f' $scpu1)
load2=$(printf '%.0f' $scpu2)

if [[ $load1 -ge $limit2 && $load2 -le $limit1 ]] ; then
    echo " CPU utilization of node1 is above 2% and node2 is below 1%"
elif [[ $load1 -le $limit1  &&  $load2 -ge $limit2 ]] ; then
    echo " CPU utilization of node2 is above 2% and node1 is below 1%"
elif [[ $load11 -ge $limit2  &&  $load2 -ge $limit2 ]] ; then
    echo "CPU utilization of node1 and node2 is above 2% "
else
    echo " Nothing to do"
fi
```

Also worth looking into few items:

- Script iterate over list of servers (server-list1.txt), but uses the load of the last server only for the message. If you expect multiple servers to be named, consider averaging, or taking the maximum/minimum value as needed.
- Using `more` is appropriate for interactive commands, Instead of `more /opt/scripts/server-list2.txt`, to iterate over list of servers from a file use `for server in $(</opt/scripts/server-list2.txt)`

Comment: I just tried with the above script but the output is 

-------------------------------------------
Server_Name   CPU(%)
-------------------------------------------
node1         1.6
-------------------------------------------
node2         3.21
-------------------------------------------
 
CPU utilization of node1 is above 2% and node2 is below 1%


I am new to scripting and not getting what is wrong with the script.

Comment: Could you please let me know what might be the reason for this error:  script.sh: line 14: ((: 1.6: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".6"). here 1.6 is the output cpu usage of node1