# sh: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Tags: bash, ssh, sh

I am creating a script where I am redirecting the output of an awk command into a loop, but it's giving me this error:

```
sh: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
sh: -c: line 3: `done < <(awk "{print}" inputfile.txt)'
```

I was able to run it against a different remote host, but this host is giving me an error. Does anyone know if some versions of sh/bash don't support that syntax, or know any alternatives to that syntax, or maybe spot a bug that I haven't been able to see? (I'm new to bash scripting, so even a point in the right direction would be helpful!)

Here is a pared-down version of my script that I was able to reproduce the issue on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

host=$1

ssh $host 'while read line
do
echo "hi";
done < <(awk "{print}" inputfile.txt)'
```

Comment: Are you running the script with `sh scriptname`?

Comment: I'm running it with ```bash scriptname```
Although I get the error when running it with either bash or sh

Comment: @Kaitlyn : From the error message, you can see that it is not bash which is producing the error message, because with bash, the message would be **bash : _bla bla_**., not **sh : ...**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the remote user on that host uses a shell that's not Bash to run the command, see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332466/118235); a way around that is to either avoid Bashisms:

```sh
ssh "$host" 'awk "{print}" inputfile.txt \
    | while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "$line"
    done'
```

which comes with its own pitfalls, see [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16854280/3266847) – alternatively, you could specify that the remote host should run Bash:

```sh
ssh "$host" <<'EOF'
bash -c 'while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < <(awk "{print}" inputfile.txt)'
EOF
```

Comment: Ok, that explanation makes sense, thank you. The second snippet specifying bash on the remote host didn't seem to work unfortunately. It's weird because I can see that bash  is installed on the remote server, but it won't use bash I guess? I'm going to try reworking the "bashisms" out like your first example.

Comment: Piping my awk results to the while loop at the beginning worked. Thank you for your help!