# export not modifying global variables

Tags: bash, shell

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal, `amd64`, Bash version `5.0.17(1)-release`.

In previous versions of Ubuntu, I've been able to write intuitive scripts to modify `PATH` in a way in which multiple entries containing the same value aren't possible.

### Source Code

My `/etc/bash.bashrc` is what is provided by the distro, and so is my `~/.bashrc`, apart from the following lines:

#### `~/.bashrc`

```sh
# ... distro defaults above

export DEBUG=y

if [ -e "$HOME/.bash_functions" ]; then
    source "$HOME/.bash_functions"
fi

if [ -d "$HOME/.bashrc.d" ]; then
    find "$HOME/.bashrc.d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sh' | sort -u | while read file ; do
        source "$file"
    done
fi
```

My `~/.bash_functions` includes my helper functions for modifying `PATH` safely:

#### `~/.bash_functions`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# log MESSAGE...
#
# Prints the provided arguments to standard error if the DEBUG variable is set to 'y'.
_log() {
    test "$DEBUG" = "y" && ( echo -n 'DEBUG: ' && echo "$@" ) >&2
}

# path_exists PATH_ENTRY
#
# Returns true if the specified path entry exists within $PATH, and false otherwise.
_path_exists() {
    path="$1" && shift
    echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | while read path_entry ; do
        test "$path" = "$path_entry" && return 0
    done && return 0

    return 1
}

# prepend_path PATH_ENTRY
#
# Pushes PATH_ENTRY to the beginning of $PATH, provided that PATH_ENTRY does not already exist in $PATH.
_prepend_path() {
    path="$1" && shift

    if ! _path_exists "$path" ; then
        _log "prepend_path - Prepending $path to PATH..."
        PATH="$path:$PATH"
    export PATH
    else
        _log "prepend_path - $path is already present in PATH, nothing to do."
    fi
}

# append_path PATH_ENTRY
#
# Pushes PATH_ENTRY to the end of $PATH, provided that PATH_ENTRY does not already exist in $PATH.
_append_path() {
    path="$1" && shift

    if ! _path_exists "$path" ; then
        _log "append_path - Appending $path to PATH..."
        PATH="$PATH:$path"
    export PATH
    else
        _log "append_path - $path is already present in PATH, nothing to do."
    fi
}
```

Finally, I have two files in `~/.bashrc.d`, one for adding Rust to the `PATH` and one for `nodenv`:

#### `~/.bashrc.d/50-rust.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -d "$HOME/.cargo/bin" ]; then
    _prepend_path "$HOME/.cargo/bin"
fi
```

#### `~/.bashrc.d/50-node.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NODENV_ROOT="$HOME/.nodenv"

if [ -d "$NODENV_ROOT/bin" ]; then
    _prepend_path "$NODENV_ROOT/bin"

    if ! _path_exists "$NODENV_ROOT/shims" ; then
        eval "$(nodenv init -)"
    fi
fi
```

---

### Issue

Since I have exported `DEBUG=y` in my `~/.bashrc`, I see output when I open a new shell:

```
DEBUG: prepend_path - Prepending /home/naftuli/.nodenv/bin to PATH...
DEBUG: prepend_path - Prepending /home/naftuli/.cargo/bin to PATH...
```

Clearly, the code is executing. If I emend my loop to print `PATH` after sourcing each file, I see that it did, in fact, modify the environment. My modifications to `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
if [ -d "$HOME/.bashrc.d" ]; then
    find "$HOME/.bashrc.d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sh' | sort -u | while read file ; do
        source "$file"
        echo "PATH=$PATH"
    done
fi
```

When I start a new shell, I observe:

```
DEBUG: prepend_path - Prepending /home/naftuli/.nodenv/bin to PATH...
PATH=/home/naftuli/.nodenv/shims:/home/naftuli/.nodenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
DEBUG: prepend_path - Prepending /home/naftuli/.cargo/bin to PATH...
PATH=/home/naftuli/.cargo/bin:/home/naftuli/.nodenv/shims:/home/naftuli/.nodenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Again, clearly it is working, but somehow `export` within those sourced files does not propagate all the way up to the actual shell environment, because after my shell starts:

```sh
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

In previous versions of Bash, this setup did work.

### Question

Why aren't my `export`s propagating upward to the shell on shell start? My code is running, and `PATH` is modified, but outside of the loop, it's as if `PATH` was never modified. What changes do I need to make in order to propagate variables upward to the shell?

Comment: Exports only propagate to child processes, not parent processes.

Comment: You're sourcing the scripts in a subshell process because it's in a pipeline.

Comment: `source "$file"` is inside of a pipe, which happens in a subshell. see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16854280/1032785

Comment: It looks to me like you could replace the `find ... | while read` loop with a simple `for file in "$HOME/.bashrc.d"/*.sh; do`

Comment: @GordonDavisson the for loop will fail if there are spaces in a filename. I don't expect there to be spaces in a filename, but `find` is my default pattern for looping in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: @NaftuliKay No, the `for` loop with wildcard handles spaces in filenames fine (as long as you double-quote `$file` when you use it). Give it a try! The only limitation I know of is that if there are no matching files, it'll run the loop once with `file` set literally to `/homepath/.bashrc.d/*.sh`. If this is a concern, use `[ -f "$file" ] && source "$file"` inside the loop.