# update stored variables in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am doing a simple script. I have to update the stored date value. For example

ss=`date`;
sleep 5;
echo $ss;

It is showing old date. How to update the date after 5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to update a variable it must be re assing: `$(..)` is a command substitution it is expanded to output of specified command.

```
ss=$(date)
...
ss=$(date)
```

`SECONDS` is a special variable which contains the number of seconds since bash process is running, to have a value changed every 5 seconds, following can be used.

```
echo $((SECONDS/5))
```

Comment: duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402537/change-variables-in-bash

Comment: Thanks Nahuel. how to reassign the same variable. If i am having an variable a=`date`;if i am going call in a loop after some time. how to reassign the current date. is there any other way